# Problem with Script not working properly when ran from Custom Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I am using 13.10 and I have created a Launcher that I want to place on my Desktop using help from other posts that I found here. My problem is (I think) that my Launcher doesn't execute my script. When I double-click on my launchers nothing happens. This is the launcher's code

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.0.1
Comment=MyLauncher
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/user/My_Prog_Aug25/Test-1.0.0-Lin64-OEM/bin/RunTest.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/emotes/face-cool.png
Name=CygnusLauncher
StartupNotify=true
```

And the  `RunTest.sh` script's code is just

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/My_Prog_Aug25/Test-1.0.0-Lin64-OEM/tools/myLibs;
./program
```

Running the script alone works and executes program but running the Launcher does nothing. The `Launcher.desktop` is executable, I used  `chmod +x Launcher.desktop` .

Any Ideas or help why this is happening and how to deal with this issue.

Comment: Please change the terminal option to true and try again, make sure your .sh is executable sudo chmod x /path/to/RunTest.sh

Comment: RunTest.sh is executable too , and I tried changing terminal option to true and nothing happens too.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yeah the typo was in my post , the launcher's code was in tact but it doesn't work

Comment: @JacobVlijm Actually , I used `/home/myuser/` in the `Exec=`

Comment: myuser is my user's name, I should have said that

Comment: tried replacing it in the script but the launcher still doesn't work.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It seems replacing the `./program` with the actual path , actually works. Thank you very much and sorry for the trouble I put you into. I read your post and it proved helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Would you mind if I made it an answer?

Comment: Antondim, browsing through old answers, I found this one. It seems to have been the solution to your problem. Would you accept it for clarity reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.desktop` file is fine. The problem is in the script; you try to make it run `program` by the command `./program`, but you didn't cd to its directory first.

You can fix it by either insert a line

```
cd /path_to_program
```

before

```
./program
```

or use the full path:

```
/path_to_program/program
```

Comment: @antondim if the answer (and the comment about the path that lead to the answer) was useful to you, would you consider accepting the answer? That way the question will not appear anymore as "unanswered".